# Is there a version of this website for digital nomads or perpetual travelers?

Tags: discussion

Is there a version of this website for digital nomads or perpetual travelers

Comment: This question does not fit on Travel Stack Exchange but I feel it does fit on our Meta site.

Comment: Can you give an example of a digital nomad/perpetual traveller question that would be off topic on both travel and expatriates stack exchange?

Answer (score 2):

No.
At least not on Stack Exchange.

It is Travel Stack Exchange or Expatriates Stack Exchange, which does not work for perpetual travelers but in some cases includes digital nomads.